# Updating an n-ary product from sop-core with a compatible sum

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, type-level-computation

I'm working with the [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core) library, and I want to write a function with the following type:

```
patch :: NS I xs -> NP Maybe xs -> NP Maybe xs
```

`xs` is a type-level list of types like `'[Int,Char,Bool]`. [`I`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP.html#t:I) is an identity functor. [`NS I xs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP.html#t:NS) is an n-ary sum type. [`NP Maybe xs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP.html#t:NP) is an n-ary product where each component may or may not exist.

`patch` should take the value from the n-ary sum and fill the corresponding slot of the n-ary product, overwriting it if it already exists. For example:

```
patched :: NP Maybe '[Int,Char,Bool]
patched = patch (Z (I 3)) (Nothing :* Nothing :* Nothing :* Nil)
-- patched == Just 3 :* Nothing :* Nothing :* Nil
```

I suspect the solution might involve the [`injections`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP.html#v:injections) function, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692296/constructing-a-n-ary-product-with-all-the-values-of-a-simple-sum-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution did not require [`injections`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP.html#v:injections) after all, but the [`expand_NS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NS.html#v:expand_NS) function which converts a sum into a product by filling the non-matching components of the product with a default value.

The trick is to build a product of *setters* that we can apply to the original record using [`liftA2_NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:liftA2_NP). When we expand the sum, the non-matching components are filled with the identity function. But we overwrite the matching component with the value in the sum.

First we need this auxiliary type

```
newtype Mendo a = Mendo { getMendo :: Maybe a -> Maybe a }
```

and the code for `patch` would be:

```
patch :: forall xs. SListI xs => NS I xs -> NP Maybe xs -> NP Maybe xs
patch piece =
  let mendos :: NP Mendo xs -- product of setters
      mendos = expand_NS (Mendo id) (liftA_NS (\(I x) -> Mendo (\_ -> Just x)) piece)
   in liftA2_NP (\(Mendo f) x -> f x) mendos
```